# Type UiViewController does not conform to protocol xxx

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10, xcode8

I have a delegate method in Objective-C code which need to implement in my project which was earlier in swift 2.3 and worked fine but after upgrading to swift 3.0 it shows error...

> Type UiViewController does not conform to protocol xxx

I have tried everything I can think of but it still isn't working.

Comment: Which protocol? Where is your code? What is defined in the protocol? Have you added all the required functions and variables that the protocol needs?

Answer (score 0):

function in protocol from Objective-C like UITableViewDataSouce has changed to a more swift style
eg:

> func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

has change to

> func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
>   just modify to new styled func,the error will be gone